# How to catch warnings not generated by warnings.warn

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I need to be able to raise exceptions in my code if a warning is raised. For example, when doing a comparison of a string and bytes object, `'b' == b'g'`, BytesWarning should be raised. I can catch it with -bb flag (ie. running `python -bb`), but want to be able to do it within the code itself.

I've tried using `warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=BytesWarning)`, but it only catches the warnings produced by `warnings.warn()`.

How can I catch warnings produced by improper code itself?

EDIT
A simple example:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=BytesWarning)
warnings.warn('message', BytesWarning)
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BytesWarning: message
```

but if I do `'b' == b'b'` instead of the call to `warnings.warn()`, it simply prints false.

With the `-bb` flag:

```
~$ python -bb
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'b' == b'b'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BytesWarning: Comparison between bytes and string
```

Comment: I'm confused- you want to raise an exception or a warning? Can you show a bit more code to give a full reproducible example?

Comment: I'd like to catch the warning and raise an exception. For example, if a user tries to do an operation such as `'b' == b'b'`, BytesWarning should be raised as an exception instead of a warning.

Comment: but `'b' == b'b'` is `False` in py 3 and `True` on py 2, so a `BytesWarning` isn't raised? You could just raise an exception directly no?

Comment: If you add the -bb flag when running the interpreter, `'b' == b'b'`, a BytesWarning is shown.

Comment: Ah got it, on python3 only like `python3 -bbc "'b' == b'b'"`

Comment: Yes, and I'm wondering if there is a way to add this into the code directly, instead of having to use a flag.